# variable in react hook is not updated

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem using react hook, when I call one function inside another, the called function contains the value of the previous state
and not the updated value with the react hook.
Previously, using classes, when updating a state value in the callback of the ,
I could call a function and it already handled the updated state.
How can I execute a second function making sure that it will handle the updated state value?

In the following example I try to pose my problem:
When I use classes and enter the value of 1, it returns a 5 (because my function multiplies it by 5),
however if I use hook and enter the value of 1, it returns 0, because that was its previous value,
if I then enter 2, it returns 5 because it is the previous result of multiplying 1 x 5.

thank you

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [numero, setNumero] = useState(0)
  const [dato, setDato] = useState(0)
  
  const handleAction = () => {
    let nuevoDato = numero * 5;
    setDato(nuevoDato);
  }

  const changeValue = (value) => {
    setNumero(value);
    handleAction();
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5 text-center">
      <h1>React</h1>  
      <input onChange={(e) => changeValue(e.target.value)} value={numero}/>
      <br/>
      <span>El numero x 5 es : {dato}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Post code as *text*, not images.

Comment: Could you please post the code instead of a picture? Thanks.

Comment: I already changed it. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**.

This is to allow the state updates to be batched together for better performance.

You can use a `useEffect` hook to respond to any changes in state, like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [numero, setNumero] = useState(0)
  const [dato, setDato] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let nuevoDato = numero * 5;
    setDato(nuevoDato);
  }, [numero])

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5 text-center">
      <h1>React</h1>  
      <input onChange={(e) => setNumero(e.target.value)} value={numero}/>
      <br/>
      <span>El numero x 5 es : {dato}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `useEffect`?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [numero, setNumero] = useState(0)
  const [dato, setDato] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setDato(numero * 5);
  }, [numero]);
 

  const changeValue = (value) => {
    setNumero(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5 text-center">
      <h1>React</h1>  
      <input onChange={(e) => changeValue(e.target.value)} value={numero}/>
      <br/>
      <span>El numero x 5 es : {dato}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```