# How to change state in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working with react typescript and can not change state in typescript. Within editing function I have setId and setEdit, so after executing editing function it does not change the state.

Here code below:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "../App.css";

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo]: any = useState([]);
    const [id, setId]: any = useState(null);
    const [edit, setEdit]: any = useState(false);

    const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const editing = (nameId: any, nameTitle: any) => {
        setId(nameId);
        setEdit(true);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(edit);
        ref.current!.value = nameTitle;
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div id="task-container">
                <div id="list-wrapper">
                    {todo.map((todo: any, index: number) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                                <div style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                                    {todo.completed == false ? (
                                        <span>{todo.title}</span>
                                    ) : (
                                            <span>{todo.title}</span>
                                        )}
                                </div>

                                <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                    <button 
                                        onClick={() => { editing(todo.id, todo.title) }} 
                                        className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Edit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Not sure what i am missing.

Comment: See the above duplicate, then move the console logs into the component body and you will see that they do update, just not until the next render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable in react hook is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019578/variable-in-react-hook-is-not-updated)

Comment: Typescript doesnt have to anything with state changes :), use hooks useEffect when something has changed , pass it to dependency array in useEffect and do your logic in useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const editing = (nameId: any, nameTitle: any) => {
    setId(nameId);
    setEdit(true);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(edit);
    ref.current!.value = nameTitle;
};
```

`setId` and `setEdit` do not execute immediately so `id` and `edit` will be logged to the console with their current (old) values.

To do something after the state has changed in a functional component, use `useEffect()`.

```
const [todo, setTodo]: any = useState([]);
const [id, setId]: any = useState(null);
const [edit, setEdit]: any = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(edit);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**, ie they will not happen immediately, only on the next re-render.

This is to allow the state updates to be batched together for better performance.

Move the console logs out into the component, or into `render`, and you'll see them change upon re-render.